# Password should not contain three or more consecutive characters of the user name

Tags: sql, passwords, password-policy

I am trying to created a SQL code that will check a password for characters that does not contain three or more consecutive characters from the user's name. Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Your database should never see a plain-text password. When a user sets a password, it should be prepended with a unique per-user salt (or nonce), then cryptographically hashed, and finally the the salt is again prepended to the result. All this happens on the client, and only now is the new password saved in the DB. This value has no resemblance to the original password. When someone tries to login, you follow the same procedure on the attempted password, and then compare hash values rather than passwords directly. So if you're looking at this in SQL, something has gone very horribly wrong.

Comment: I am trying to validate the password entered by the user.

Comment: The database shouldn't know what the password is. All you store in the DB is a value altered as described above. When someone logs in, you alter their attempted value in the same way, and then compare the results, and this is pretty much always done **in client code**. This means checking things like matching characters in a username at this time makes no sense. Even if this is learning code, this is one of those things that's too important to do the wrong way, even in student work.